# lambda function Health Status: unhealthy (Health checks failed)

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-application-load-balancer

I had lambda function and alb deployed in AWS. My goal is to invoke the lambda function by sending request with postman. I can get a response from alb, but `502 Bad Gateway` error from lambda function.
Following is what I observed:

1. During the deployment process, I can see that alb was doing health check, probably took around 30 sec to 1 min, then shows health status: unhealthy.
2. Health status of this lambda function is unhealthy.
3. There are 0 records on the lambda function CloudWatch logs. No data found from Recent invocations.

I suspect that there are 2 factors may cause this issue:

1. Incorrect proxy setting, so the request was never forwarded to the lambda function.
2. Malformed response from lambda function.

Thoughts:
If there is 0 records in the lambda function CloudWatch, is that means the requests was never forwarded to lambda function at all? Even if the lambda response format is wrong, there should have a record indicates that lambda function received a request. Am I right?
[image]

[image]

I am trying to narrow down the root cause. please advise. Thank you!